# Split a csv file through commas in python

Tags: python, csv

i am writing a program that opens csv files, works with the data and outputs that data to a new csv file. How would i open the csv file and make a 3d array out of it? I don't want to use the csv module to do this as i cant get it to work with my code.

Comment: Show us your code and take a look [here on how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    array = file.readlines()
    array = [row.split(',') for row in array]
```